# Should I submit an expression of interest for another position although I still have 1.5 years left in my current contract?

Tags: postdocs, job-search

I am a postdoc with slightly more than 1.5 out of 3 years left in my contract. Recently I have received an email about a postdoctoral position in another country, which interests me. The position is not yet formally advertised, but potential candidates are invited to submit a brief expression of interest, and to indicate the date they will be available.

Is it a common practice to submit an expression of interest although I will only be available 1.5 years from now?

Comment: How binding is your contract? In many cases, it's understood and accepted that a postdoc will leave early if they get offered a better job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a common practice to submit an expression of interest although I will only be available 1.5 years from now?

I wouldn't say it is "common practice", simply because it seems relatively pointless. While starting dates for academic jobs are usually flexible, 1.5 years of delay for a postdoc seems like a stretch. Many postdocs are hired on specific projects, and the project in question would be half-over before you even begin. Even for postdocs paid by some sort of fellowship, the start date usually isn't *that* flexible. Of course this does not stop you from asking, but I would not get my hopes up too high.

Comment: There also are times where the solicitation of expressions of interest is in turn used to help secure the funding that would in the end pay for the other position. In which case there may already be a built-in time delay for the next position. If it takes 9 months to get the grant approved, an availability of 18 months from now doesn't look all that bad.

Comment: @WillieWong I have never heard of that, but I am willing to be educated. However, if it isn't specifically advertised as such in the call, this would seem slightly insincere to me. If I announce a position, I would expect them to already have funding, right?

Comment: That's why the position is not _formally announced/advertised_. I've certainly seen e-mails that says "We anticipate having funding available for blah. Interested candidates should send a short expression of interest with CV attached. We will contact you again once the actual search had begun." And yeah, sometimes these CVs are collected and shown to the dean to say: Look, these are the calibre of people that we can be hiring if you would only please approve that budget we gave you.

Comment: Also, if there is a firm start-date requirement, would they not have advertised it as such directly? The only reasons I can conceive of asking for availability in the announcement are (a) they are in fact somewhat flexible about the start date (b) they want to fill the position right now, so they will weigh availability against quality when they make the decision. It may not hurt to send an e-mail to ask which of the two cases it is. (In the latter, I agree that 1.5 years out is likely too long to wait for the potential employer.)